# How to add row in table and in mysql using button or link?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm creating a simple database of children and their birthday.

[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Q9T9u/3/)

```
<?php
$chname1x = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["chname1"]);
$chbdate1x = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["chbdate1"]);
$chname2x = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["chname2"]);
$chbdate2x = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["chbdate2"]);
$chname3x = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["chname3"]);
$chbdate3x = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["chbdate3"]);
$chname4x = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["chname4"]);
$chbdate4x = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["chbdate4"]);
$chname5x = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["chname5"]);
$chbdate5x = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["chbdate5"]);

    $dbhost='localhost';
$dbuser='root';
$dbpass='';

$conn=mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass) or die ('Could not connect to mysql');

$dbname='onlinepdsdb';
mysql_select_db($dbname);


if ($_POST['submitbutton'])
{
 $query="INSERT INTO children (chname1,chbdate1,chname2,chbdate2,chname3,chbdate3,chname4,chbdate4,chname5,chbdate5) VALUES ('$chname1x', '$chbdate1x','$chname2x', '$chbdate2x','$chname3x', '$chbdate3x','$chname4x', '$chbdate4x','$chname5x', '$chbdate5x')";

    mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
    echo "The user $uid has been succesfully registered.";
    echo $query;
    echo $uid;
}



<center>
<form method='POST' action='formchildren.php'>
<table border='3' style='width:700px'>
    <tr bgcolor='#3399FF'>
        <td colspan='2' class='head2' height='20'>NAME OF CHILD (Write full name and list all)</td>
        <td colspan='3' class='head2' height='20'>DATE OF BIRTH (mm/dd/yyyy)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='numbering'>1.</td>
        <td style='text-align:center;'>
            <input type='text' name='chname1' size='45' maxlength='200'>
        </td>
        <td style='text-align:center;'>
            <input type='date' name='chbdate1' size='45' maxlength='50'>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=6 class='step' height='10'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='numbering'>2.</td>
        <td style='text-align:center;'>
            <input type='text' name='chname2' size='45' maxlength='200'>
        </td>
        <td style='text-align:center;'>
            <input type='date' name='chbdate2' size='45' maxlength='50'>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=6 class='step' height='10'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='numbering'>3.</td>
        <td style='text-align:center;'>
            <input type='text' name='chname3' size='45' maxlength='200'>
        </td>
        <td style='text-align:center;'>
            <input type='date' name='chbdate3' size='45' maxlength='50'>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=6 class='step' height='10'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='numbering'>4.</td>
        <td style='text-align:center;'>
            <input type='text' name='chname4' size='45' maxlength='200'>
        </td>
        <td style='text-align:center;'>
            <input type='date' name='chbdate4' size='45' maxlength='50'>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=6 class='step' height='10'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='numbering'>5.</td>
        <td style='text-align:center;'>
            <input type='text' name='chname5' size='45' maxlength='200'>
        </td>
        <td style='text-align:center;'>
            <input type='date' name='chbdate5' size='45' maxlength='50'>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><input type='SUBMIT' name='submitbutton'></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

I created here a 5 rows, but if the children is more than 5 there is no more rows. I want to put a link/button that if clicked will add a row in table and in mysql but I don't have any idea how.

Comment: Seriously? JS Fiddle? Your question is super vague, perhaps you should try something first

Comment: Add a form with a submit button which will pass POST data through the page and execute a MySQL query.

Comment: are u good with php ?

Comment: Its just a part of my code sorry. Actually its a whole form and it have PHP for the input to store in the database.

Comment: Why are you stating *mm/dd/yyyy* as date format in table header?

Comment: please show us your php code ?

Comment: its a guide for those who will input, if their browser cannot support DATE tag of HTML5.

Comment: If that is all of your PHP script you don't even connect to your database server before trying to do your insert. This is to little and to vague information to help you.

Comment: Your button isn't named "submitbutton", so if ($_POST['submitbutton']) will fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jQuery` `.append()`

here are the source [jQuery Append](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

using append:
e.g. by click a button, you can append another `textbox and dropdown list`
It's in you on how you can do this.. This is just a tip. ;)

example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/lian23/Sz73b/

Comment: Thanks. I don't know anything about jquery, I'm only a beginner in Javascript but your solution is very helpful. I think

Answer (score 0):

Your form's submit button fields are backwards. Switch the type & name.
The type should be "submit", and the name "submitbutton"

eg

```
<input type='submit' name='submitbutton'>
```

This way, the HTML will be correct and your PHP code will be looking for the right field name:

```
if ($_POST['submitbutton'])
```

Comment: Your welcome. Please accept/upvote the answer if this has solved your problem.